# Using Mirth Connect JavaScript to output a barcode font to PDF

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, mirth

Mirth Connect uses iTextpdf and barcode 128 is not an included font.  I downloaded code128.ttf font, but how can I reference this with javascript in Mirth Connect?  Maybe someone has a Mirth channel that does this or something similar?

Another possibility is Mirth Connect has a Document Writer template option which can use HTML/CSS to reference the local font.  I tried many variations of HTML/Inline CSS to no avail.

Comment: Can you state what your channel inputs are, what your source transformers are doing, what your destinations are and any transformers, and what your desired output is?

Comment: Can you get outputs that are correct with ANY font? IOW are we just dealing with "use this font" or are there other issues?

Answer (score 1):

I did it by writing the barcode to a temporary file and referencing that in the Document Writer HTML.

Add a JavaScript transformer step to your destination Document Writer:

```
// Generate your barcode
var barcodeContents = "0123456789 hello"
var code128 = new Packages.com.lowagie.text.pdf.Barcode128();
code128.setCode(barcodeContents);

// Convert to image
var image = code128.createAwtImage(java.awt.Color.BLACK, java.awt.Color.WHITE);
var bufferedImage = new java.awt.image.BufferedImage(image.getWidth(),image.getHeight(), java.awt.image.BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
var graphics = bufferedImage.getGraphics();
graphics.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);

// Write to JPG file
var filename = UUIDGenerator.getUUID().toString() + '.jpg';
javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpg", new java.io.File("C:\\Temp\\Barcodes\\" + filename));

// Save the filename to use in your Document Writer
$c('BarcodeFilename', filename);
```

Then just reference the image in your HTML template:

```
<img src="/temp/Barcodes/${BarcodeFilename}"/>
```

As a bonus you can add a Javascript Writer destination to delete the image afterwards:

```
var filename = $c('BarcodeFilename');
FileUtil.delete("C:\\Temp\\Barcodes\\" + filename);
```

Comment: This works really well

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of barcode image generator libraries for Java. Create your own Java class that does everything you need, deploy to the /custom-lib folder in the Mirth installation and call the class in your channel's source or destination transformer JS step.

Comment: That solution worked for me... I had help with this, but he created a Java class and called it from the Mirth channel.  Thanks Shamil!